# How do conditions work?

Tags: anylogic

I'm building an epidemiological model for pertussis in Italy, where the vaccination schedule is on the III, V and IX month of life...then there is a booster dose at 4 - 6 years and another one at 14.
The age of agents reproduces the distribution of italian population, and I used the data from the last century to split the initial population in different states. While I took data on daiyly contact from another paper and on these data every agents connects with other agents.

I want to reproduce the epidemiology on Pertussis in Italy from 2006 to 2014...so i'm interested in the number of infected people

[image]

new agents (born during the simulation) enter in state S...in their third month of life (from 60 to 89 days old) agents can be vaccinated and chage state (go to V1)...I have the daily probability of changing state (ProbVaccD)...this is the code I wrote in the transition:

`condition: age() >= 60./365 && age()<90./365
guard: randomTrue(main.ProbVaccD)`

The time of the model is "days" and "age()" is a function defined as `return time(YEAR) - birthDate;` where "birthDate" is a variable, storing the time(YEAR) of the model when agents were born.

What I want is the condition to be evaluated every day, therefore I added a "cyclic event" with "recurrence time 1 days" and `action: onChange();`...is this correct?

The point I'm worried about is the fact that some agents (those in state Ip, Is, R1, R2 and R3) daily send messages to all the agents they are connected with...

Let's suppose an agent receive 8 messages, then the condition is evaluated 8 times (one for each message) + 1 (for the "onChange();) function?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: your action code is just "onChange()"? What's the point?

Comment: maybe it is useless xD  I have understood that conditions are evaluated only when something changes in the agents...since I want the condition to be evaluated every day, I thought to put "onChange()"....likely i got something wrong :) also because I haven't found much information on this function on the help

Comment: Ok, let's go by steps. What are you getting with your code? Could you update your post with an image of your flowchart?

Comment: @luizfvpereira it is my first time with AnyLogic...so the flowchart is confused as I am confused :))  I want to reproduce the epidemiology of pertussis...i'm interested in the number of Infected over 9 years (2006 to 2014)

Comment: Can you describe the model, entirely, by words. Don't explain what you've done but what you wanted to model!